# Scale 'priority' where 1 is larger than 3 for graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I simply want change a scale on graph so that 1 is largest value and three is smallest. I have data in excel. A function would preferred as I do not want to simply swap the values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get $1$ above $3$ in Excel.  A kludge is to negate the data so the range is $-1$ to $-3$.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in Raffael Marty's book 'Applied Security Visualization'.
=INT(1/A1*1000000)

```
    2   500000
    2   500000
    2   500000
    3   333333
    3   333333
    3   333333
    3   333333
    1   1000000
    1   1000000
    1   1000000
    1   1000000
    1   1000000
```

Where A1 is the cell with Priority score.